# Como mover um botão em CSS?

Tags: html, css

Bom dia! Estou enfrentando problemas com o posicionamento de um botão em CSS.

Queria mudar cada um destes 4 botões para um lado em especifico, mas não sei como.

```css
.button {
           background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
           border: none;
           color: white;
           padding: 16px 32px;
           text-align: center;
           text-decoration: none;
           display: inline-block;
           font-size: 60px;
           margin: 40px 2px;
           -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
           transition-duration: 0.4s;
           cursor: pointer;
         }
         
         
         .button5 {
           background-color: white;
           color: black;
           border: 2px solid #555555;
         }

         #historia{
            
            
         }
         #cartazes{
            
            
         }
         #fotos{
            
            
         }
         #videos{
            
            
         }

         
         .button5:hover {
           background-color: #555555;
           color: white;
         }
```

```html
     
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul >
   
      
         </head>
         <body>
         
         
         <button onclick="location.href='http://localhost/pap/historia.html'" type="button" class="button button5" id="historia">História</button>
         <button class="button button5" id="cartazes">Cartazes</button>
         <button class="button button5" id="fotos">Fotos</button>
         <button class="button button5" id="videos">Vídeos</button>
```

E aqui está o código do css e hmtl dos botões.

Eu sei que tenho que criar um id para cada botão mas não sei o que escrevo em cada um...

E aqui esta o menu onde estão os botões que quero mover.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual lado especifico você que mudar?

Comment: Como vc gostaria de deixa-los?

Comment: Sem falar o que você quer fazer só vai gerar chutes como respostas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem várias formas de fazer isso, a mais fácil acredito ser com `position:absolute`. Primeiro vc coloca o pai e todos os elementos "pai" com altura de e largura de 100% para ocupar a tela inteira, depois vc coloca o pai do `position:relative` e os filhos com `position:absolute`. Dessa forma vc pode aliar os botões um em cada canto com `top`, `left`, `bottom` e `right`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 60px;
  /* margin: 40px 2px; */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.button5 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
}

#historia{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#cartazes{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#fotos{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

}
#videos{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}


.button5:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
    <button onclick="location.href='http://localhost/pap/historia.html'" type="button" class="button button5" id="historia">História</button>
    <button class="button button5" id="cartazes">Cartazes</button>
    <button class="button button5" id="fotos">Fotos</button>
    <button class="button button5" id="videos">Vídeos</button>
  </ul>
</div>
```